# How to configure client using Configuration of hadoop-core in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have several questions on using the client of hadoop.

1. How can I specify username and password ? if can't, the client will use the user of windows to access hadoop, but I doubt if it is secure.
2. How many parameters can I set using Configuration ? Can I set username and password into it ??

Comment: Which username/password are you referring to? Provide more clarity on the query. There is no theoretical limit on the # of parameters than can be set on the Configuration.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the method of type of FileSystem which named get(URI uri, Configuration configuration, String username) with jar version 0.20.205.0. it don't need password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the method of type of FileSystem which named get(URI uri, Configuration configuration, String username) with jar version 0.20.205.0. it don't need password.
thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

For (1):

Hadoop's security is not password based but rather *kerberos-based*. You can read more on its security architecture [here](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/authorization-and-authentication-in-hadoop/) and find a guide on configuring it for most recent releases [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Introduction+to+Hadoop+Security).

The API you noticed (per your above comment), is a mechanism to impersonate other usernames (if allowed by the master server(s)), not a security measure.

For (2):

You can theoretically set as many config key-value parameters as your JVM memory would let you, as long as it is under `mapred.user.jobconf.limit` (defaults to 5 MB), as restricted at the JobTracker.